# Calculate future state given hypothetical action

Tags: javascript, redux

How might I figure out what the state will become (without changing the current state) given a hypothetical action? Should I create a new store using the current state, then dispatch my action to that?

(I've got hyperlinks that should dispatch an action when clicked, and I want to set the href attribute to the future URL, mainly so that Open Link in New Tab works.)

Comment: will this action involve data fetching? will it be observe by more than one reducer? we need some context. obviously the simple answer is get a  deep copy of your state and pass it to your reducer along with the action and that will be new next state. but your requirements are a bit strange. you want to calculate the url of the link after you click on the link?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon Haha, that is indeed very obvious. I'm embarrassed I asked! Thanks for pointing out the obvious. (I'm new to this.)

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon To satiate curiosity, I'll clarify a bit. I'll calculate the link's URL when the element is created. For example, I've got <a is="state-modifier" action="set-prop">...</a> which, when clicked, changes the state in a way that adds a parameter to the query string. I want its href to be set when the element is created so that the element then looks like <a href="/?prop=true">...</a>.

Comment: I'm still confused about your use case. When the link is clicked it's supposed to change the state in a way that changes the query string in its own URL? How does calculating a hypothetical future state fit in with generating these URLs? Are you trying to propagate the whole existing state in the URL and add or modify a certain param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple case you could just call the reducer directly:

```js
hypotheticalState = reducer(store.getState(), action);
```

In a more complicated case I suppose you would have to do what you described:

> create a new store using the current state, then dispatch [an] action to that